# How can I disable auto-correct on an input box?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, autocorrect

I'd like to disable auto-correct on an input box in my app. I've found a solution for objective-c that looks like this:

```
    UITextField* f = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    f.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

I've tried implementing it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
    // in my viewController
    @IBOutlet weak var webAddressInput: UITextField!
    // in my viewDidLoad
    webAddressInput.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
```

### How can I disable auto-correct on an input box in Swift?

Comment: It doesn't work because that is not Swift

Comment: Sorry if I was too vague. The term UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo is not Swift. You need to translate the code into Swift.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were just not knowing where to look for the source of the issue. - In my book, the best place to look on this topic is the appendix, where it talks about how Objective-C enums are turned into Swift enums / structs: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift's treatment of enums takes a little getting used to. If you search on UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo in the docs, it leads you to the umbrella type UITextAutocorrectionType.

The Swift definition of that type is

```
enum UITextAutocorrectionType : Int {
    case Default
    case No
    case Yes
}
```

In Swift you use `type.value`, so this would be

```
UITextAutocorrectionType.No
```

Your line would be

```
webAddressInput.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
```

(Although, looking at the docs, I don't see an `autocorrectionType` property on UITextField)

Comment: thanks duncan! Now I understand what @matt meant by translate. I can probably apply **type.value** to objective-c across the board. Sweet.

Comment: Yup. That seems to be the general pattern with defining the enums from Objective-C APIs in Swift. The name of each enum tends to be LongCamelCasePrefixWithUniqueEnding, and in Swift, the enum type is the first, common part (LongCamelCasePrefix) and the specific enum is the unique second part (WithUniqueEnding), so the specific enum is written as LongCamelCasePrefix.WithUniqueEnding. I've seen some Objective-C enums where type of the whole enum group is the same as the prefix, and some not.

Comment: Wow, you actually just made something click for me. I'm new to Swift and I've been struggling with interpreting the docs for a while.  When you explained the enum in your answer you've in turn showed me how to approach what I find in the docs. Thanks again. :)